# Есть ли программы для Windows, способные подобрать tor onion имя желаемое длиной в 56 символов?

Tags: tor, onion

1. Например для Ubuntu 14.4 "последней по стилю под нормальную", не будет обновлений для длины адреса в 56 байт (там нет поддержки, LTS кончился досрочно в сравнении с Win 7, где бы в 14.4 LTS кончился бы в 2024.4).
2. Виртуалки будут лагать, потому нужен только Windows.

Comment: Если верить [некоторым тестам](https://www.phoronix.com/review/windows11-wsl2-good/4), WSL2-виртуалка иногда оказывается даже быстрее чем нативный линукс, так что на этом фоне заявления в стиле «Виртуалки будут лагать» выглядят странно

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 проекта на гитхабе:

[cathugger/mkp224o](https://github.com/cathugger/mkp224o) - сборки под Windows в Releases

[rdkr/oniongen-go](https://github.com/rdkr/oniongen-go) - нужно собирать самому, написан на Go